# Conditional formatting rule to apply to across row

Tags: google-sheets

I have set a conditional rule so that if a specific cell equals "y" then the cell background is changed to green.

Is there a way to apply this rule so that it will change the background colour for the row the cell is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much.

Assuming the value is in column A.

1. Format>Conditional Formatting
2. Enter `A:J` under Apply to Range (or extend beyond J if you need to)
3. Format cells if Custom formula `=$A:$A="y"`

That'll get you [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LgVoTK-hJpP8fxRvbm9jou0N0DhO7x449tpwxRpsM3I/edit#gid=0).